# Call to a member function prepare() on null in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to fetch data from database using MySQLi.

Code from `class.php`

```
class main{
    public $host="localhost";
    public $username="root";
    public $password="";
    public $db_name= "db_tvw";
    private $img_path    = 'slider_img_upload/';

    public function __construct(){
        $this->run= new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "database connection is fail";
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function select_data_from_db($table_name ,$run){
        $stmt=$run->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table_name); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $total_count=$result->num_rows;
        $result= array();
        if($total_count>0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                $result[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

---

Code from `index.php`

```
<?php $myrow=$obj->select_data_from_db("home_slider",$run); ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo  $myrow['id']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo  $myrow['title']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo  $myrow['description']; ?> </td>
</tr>
```

---

Error which I am getting :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: run in 
D:\Xampp\htdocs\admin\slider_fetch_data.php on line 24.

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in 
D:\Xampp\htdocs\admin\config.php on line 116.
```

Comment: Where you are creating object of `main` class? show that code.

Comment: In class.php in end of the file here i am creating a object of the main class code is here :
     public function url($url){
     header("location:".$url);
 } }
    $obj = new main;

Comment: Just as a matter of style - class names usually start with a capital, so Main would be preferable.  Also, $run is an instance variable, so should be referenced with `this` -in this case: `$stmt=$this->run->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table_name); `

Comment: I think no matter small and capital letters of class name can you give me any other solution.

Comment: now  i am getting this error :    Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in D:\Xampp\htdocs\admin\config.php on line 122 my other errors are complete

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $myrow = new main();
    $myrow=$obj->select_data_from_db("home_slider",$myrow->run);
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo  $myrow['id']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo  $myrow['title']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo  $myrow['description']; ?> </td>
</tr>
```

You can try it

Comment: Hey after trying this code i am getting these errors:                                          Notice: Undefined variable: query in D:\Xampp\htdocs\admin\config.php on line 122

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in D:\Xampp\htdocs\admin\config.php on line 122                                               

 Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\Xampp\htdocs\admin\slider_fetch_data.php on line 29

Comment: Can you share your linkedin id with me for discussion regarding this issue.

Comment: You get errors because query return null. In select_data_from_db function you change: while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$result[] = $row;
}}

Comment: yeah thank you so much i am trying this code now am getting this error:         Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in D:\Xampp\htdocs\admin\config.php on line 122

Comment: not sure but i think function select_data_from_db should change to : `public function select_data_from_db($table_name, $run) {
  $stmt =  $run->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $table_name);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result();

  return $result->fetch_assoc();
   }`

Comment: ok thank you soo much but after using last line return $result->fetch_assoc(); } not get any solution. i am getting a same error.

Answer (score 0):

Since on your class.php you initialized the run with this code

```
$this->run= new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);
```

i think you don't need

```
public function select_data_from_db($table_name ,$run){}
```

remove the second parameter

---

it should be this

```
public function select_data_from_db($table_name){}
```

---

This is the correct code (if i am not wrong, and the mysqli working)

on class.php

```
class main{
    public $host="localhost";
    public $username="root";
    public $password="";
    public $db_name= "db_tvw";
    private $img_path    = 'slider_img_upload/';

    public function __construct(){
        $this->run= new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "database connection is fail";
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function select_data_from_db($table_name){
        $stmt=$this->run->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table_name); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $total_count=$result->num_rows;
        $result= array();
        if($total_count>0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                $result[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
...
```

---

on index.php

```
<?php $myrow=$obj->select_data_from_db("home_slider"); ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo  $myrow['id']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo  $myrow['title']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo  $myrow['description']; ?> </td>
</tr>
```